# Hyper-V replication - avhdx files and checkpoints on replica target, but none on source

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I am replicating from one Hyper-V server to another, on the source there are no checkpoints shown in Hyper-V manager, and a single vhdx file.

On the target, there is a checkpoint from months ago along with avhdx files, and this checkpoint cannot be deleted.

Any ideas please? Is it possible to delete these or just resync from scratch again?
[image: replica with checkpoints]

Answer (score 4):

Hyper-V Replica doesn't attempt to replicate checkpoints.  It's a disaster recovery strategy for VMs, and it only replicates the currently running instance of the VM (and not the frozen moments in the past that those checkpoints represent.)

What Replica does do, however, is create checkpoints periodically while it does this replication.  Each checkpoint that you see on the recovery server represents an application-consistent moment that you might recover if you do fail over.  These don't exist on the primary server because you can't "recover" a lost VM on the machine that hasn't lost it yet.

You should be able to delete the checkpoint on the recovery server.  I'm not sure why that's failing.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your replica did you select to create additional recovery points? if you did that would explain the existence of the checkpoint on the replica. if you decide to resync you don't have to do it from scratch you can sync to an existing VM. This link gives details:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2013/08/27/using-an-existing-vm-for-initial-replication-in-hyper-v-replica/

you would stop the replication then use the replica VM as the target for the new sync.

Comment: Actually, user-created checkpoints aren't replicated.  See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the replication of victim VM, then it will start automatic merging process. Once it gets complete the .avhdx file will cleared.

Or

You can simply restart the victim VM